# Best approach for public key encryption in .net

Tags: c#, java, security, encryption

I have a system that needs to share data with another system. I would like to encrypt the files following a public/private key method as opposed to just AES.

The other system is in Java so I want to make sure my methods are capable of working with other platforms. I will encrypt with the public key and we will give them the decrypt key to have in their system

Any advice would be great.

Do I need to use something like bouncy castle or can I use native code?

Comment: If you have a secure mechanism for transmitting the decryption key without tampering or eavesdropping then **why aren't you using that mechanism for transmitting the secret documents in the first place?**

Comment: Your comment doesn't make much sense. 1. The key may have been already transferred, the documents yet to be created. 2. The key may be many orders of magnitude smaller. 3. The decryption key doesn't need to be transfered at all, since this is asymmetric crypto

Comment: @maaartinus: All good reasons to use crypto. Do we have any reason to suppose that any of those actually apply to the system being discussed? Its parameters are completely vague and the reasons for using crypto are unstated. We don't know the resource being protected or the proposed attacks, or the vulnerabilities for which crypto is proposed as a defense. I'm asking leading questions for a reason here.

Comment: Here is the use case. we need to send order data to a ftp server (not in our control) to have a java backend application grab the files off the ftp server every 5 minutes. I am trying to drop these txt files encrypted in a way that if my webserver is compromised then the txt files are still worthless.

Comment: @Quotient: Then there's no need for asymmetric crypto. Why can't you use a secret key instead?

Comment: @Eric Lippert the resource is a text/txt file. Each txt file will be about 100kb and contain order information. User info, account info, inventory stuff, and some backend data for the other db to get. We will be sending the files to FTP and not sftp so we have to protect the contents and not the wire. Not my choice here I would love some secure services over static files anyway. Just looking for thoughts from the community. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I considered just AES but. I was worried that my webserver would get hacked and someone could get the AES key from the code

Comment: @Eric: I was -- probably too optimistically -- assuming he knows what he's doing. As we can see now, he can transmit the keys, only the asymmetric makes no sense.

Comment: @Quotient: This makes no sense, does it? There's a party encrypting the data, it has only the public key, but a successful cracker reads the data *before* encryption. The other party has the private key, nothing more to say.

Comment: @maaartinus good point. I had not considered that if they compromise the server then... out of luck anyway because they will get the data as it is made or encrypted. So the only reason to encrypt now is for transmission and the event of the FTP server getting hacked. Maybe I am back to just AES now?

Comment: @Quotient: I'd go for Bouncy Castle, as it works both for C# and Java. Having the same library on both sites eliminates nearly all possible interoperability problems.

Comment: @Quotient: Actually, compromising the server using AES gives the attacker all past documents as well. This is a difference, not sure if it's worth it.

Comment: m@aaartinus ok we will go with bouncy on this. I will destroy the file after it is written to ftp. Ideally it never hits the file system on the server. Thanks for the all the help and banter.

Answer (score 4):

Your proposal is *bizarre*. You are Alice. You wish to send a secret message to system "Bob" that only Bob can decrypt. Your proposal is that *Alice* generates a key pair for Bob, then somehow magically gets Bob's private key from Alice to Bob, and then Alice presumably keeps the public key secret.  If you have a mechanism whereby Alice can communicate the private key to Bob then *why do you need cryptography in the first place?* You already have a secure channel!

Maybe it is too expensive to use the secure channel for the large documents. Even if it is, **your scheme is the exact opposite of how public key encryption is supposed to work.**  What you want is for *Bob* to generate the key pair and transmit the *public* key in the clear to *Alice*.

Now the problem that Bob has to solve is *how does Alice know that the public key actually came from Bob*?  An attacker could be sending their public key to Alice and telling Alice that it came from Bob.  **This is the important problem that you should be solving.**  The strength of the entire scheme rests upon Bob being able to get his public key to Alice successfully.

What you really need to make this work is a trusted third party, say, Verisign or some other certifying authority, whose public key is well known. Alice and Bob can both generate their own key pairs, and then Verisign can vouch that Alice's public key and Bob's public key came from Alice and Bob, respectively. That's the foundation that the system's security rests upon.

Furthermore: public key crypto is *slow* for large messages. Usually what you want to do is use public key crypto as part of a key negotiation. That is generate a secret key in a symmetric cryptosystem for a particular "session", use public key crypto as the secure channel to communicate the session key from Alice to Bob, and then encrypt everything else using the fast symmetric algorithm.

Comment: I agree with you but.. the java vendor in this case is being dumb and want us to do all the work. They offered to come up with some custom replace numbers and letter non sense and we are pushing for something standard.... nevertheless I agree with you. They should give us the public key and we never know the private one but in the gap of ether this is all I got. Thanks for your interest and making sure I am sane.

Answer (score 1):

Have a key pair for both system. Install the public key from System1 into System2 and the public key from System2 into System1.

Both Systems now can encrypt data that only the other system can view. Use that to exchange a random AES key.

Use that AES key to encrypt the rest of the traffic

Public keys are just used to validate who you're talking to nd to sign stuff, AES is used the rest of the time.